# Plotting survival curve - controlling labels

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I am plotting survival curves for different strata with the following code

```
library(survival)
library(rms)
survplot(npsurv(formula =Surv(time, event)~group, data=df ), legend.pos = 'bottom')
```

On resulting graph line labels are not positioned well, as they overlap and run off the graph. How can I control positioning of labels? I am happy with just creating simple legend instead of putting labels next to line.

Comment: We have no idea what your plot looks like because we can't run your code (we don't have your data). Be sure to include a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample data. That will make it easier to help you.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the code, near the end  you see:

```
 if (labelc) 
        labcurve(curves, curve.labels, type = ltype, lty = lty, 
            col. = col, lwd = lwd, opts = label.curves)
```

And the `label.curves` argument should be a list as described in `?labcurve`. I found that the plot produced by the first example on `?survplot` would allow arbitrary adjustment with the use of the "locator" option to method:

```
survplot(f, age=mean(age), sex, conf.int=.95, 
         label.curves=list(method="locator"))
```

There are quite a few other options. The function `putKey` also is described on the same help page as `?labcurve` if you would like to use a legend.